# Grab input from chrome html popup to then pass through a function in content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Building Chrome Extension to search site through HTML, but eventlistener doesn't seem to be grabbing anything.

I have the input in the popup html, but I am unable to register a listener to that input.

how would i get the input text in the content.js listener?

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Search Site",
  "description": "Search Birds & Fish on https://obscurecritters.weebly.com",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "extension_script.html",
    "default_icon": "Extension_Icon.png",
    "default_title": "Get pages source"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
       "matches":["https://obscurecritters.weebly.com/*"],
       "css": ["style.css"],
       "js": ["content.js"]
    }
 ]
}
```

extension_script.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <input name="animal_name" placeholder="Search..." />
      <button id="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

content.js

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('Running on Load')
    const f = document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', search_images);
  });

function seach_images() {
    console.log('Running Search Images')
    let all_gallery_photos = document.querySelectorAll('.galleryImage')
    console.log(all_gallery_photos)

    all_gallery_photos.forEach(filter_images)
}

function filter_images() {
 //ignore for now
}
```

Comment: The popup is a separate page not related to the web page, so you need a separate popup.js loaded in your html to use the button. To see devtools right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.